# See patch messages in real-time

Tags: ios, libpd

Is it possible to send messages to a patch using libPd for iOS and see visual updates in real-time? I tried loading the patch from the simulator directory into the editor, then interacting with my to send Pd messages, however no visual updates happened.

Does libpd use the patch-file as a state store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where do you want to see the visual updates? libPd itself is not "visual", the only "visual" part of your application would the GUI *you* have written for the app.

- whenever you send a message to libPd, update your GUI
- whenever you receive a message from libPd, update your GUI

Comment: Thanks, I was just starting out and misunderstood how the Visual Designer worked. . You know how the designer can show state of inlets? On/off, etc? I wondered if it could be updated in real-time as a user interacts with a patch via libPD . .